# Textarea and text-indent: placeholder doesn't work properly on EDGE

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I've got a strange issue with placeholders on Edge browser. So in my project, I need to use a textarea with the specified **text-indent** parameter. On edge, however, the placeholder is rendered further than expected.

[image]

I created a small pen for you to test: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/boVaLK

```css
textarea {
  width:500px;
  height: 200px;
  text-indent: 25px;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="start typing"></textarea>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Hope this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910797/edge-input-placeholder-not-aligned-with-text

Answer (score 0):

For you problem you can use `-ms-input-placeholder` for applying css for place holder but if you go through the documentation of MDN you come to know that it is not a good to use this in production and bad thing as per my knowledge there is no other way to work this in Microsoft edge. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-ms-input-placeholder

```
textarea::-ms-input-placeholder{
  text-indent: 0px;
}
```

Comment: No, doesn't work, unfortunately. Well, crappy MS Edge.